# Creating streamlit chatbot as pop-up box in react app

Tags: python, reactjs, chatbot, streamlit

I am working on a chatbot built on Streamlit, and I want to embed the Streamlit chatbot UI and backend into my React frontend as a popup instead of a standalone page for the chatbot.

Is there any possibility to make this happen?
Do you have any tips or posts to guide me through it?

Note: I am new to streamlit.

I haven't found any resources that explain how to embed the Streamlit chatbot as a frame into a React app.